# How to deploy an Excel/Word Add-In in a Company?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, microsoft-office-2010, active-directory

I've an Excel and a Word Add-In and want to deploy them for a whole company. They are working with Windows Serer 2008 R2, Windows 7 and Office 2010. The network is managed with Active Directory.

The Add-In should be deployed and switched on on all Accounts / PCs automatically.

How can I do that? Are there any special things the Add-In has to full fill?

Comment: How your network is organized? Do you use Active Directory for user accounts?

Comment: Yes we use Active Directory.

Comment: SF question? <!-- filler -->

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Add-In installer is an MSI package then you can deploy it via GroupPolicy:

[How to use Group Policy to remotely install software in Windows Server 2003 and in Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816102)

Comment: No, it's a straight forward .xlam file.

Comment: Then you can pack it into an MSI: [How do I deploy a VBA Excel Add-In (foo.xlam) using an msi installer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308744/how-do-i-deploy-a-vba-excel-add-in-foo-xlam-using-an-msi-installer)

Answer (score 3):

you can insert this code in your *.xlam in the sheet "ThisWorkBook" this code install and activate the current AddIns, just by opening

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim oXL As Object, oAddin As Object
    URL = Me.Path & "\"
    normalUrl = Application.UserLibraryPath ' Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\AddIns"
    AddinTitle = Mid(Me.Name, 1, Len(Me.Name) - 5)

    If URL <> normalUrl Then
        If MsgBox("Can you Install AddIns ?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            Set oXL = Application ' CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            oXL.Workbooks.Add
            Me.SaveCopyAs normalUrl & Me.Name
            Set oAddin = oXL.AddIns.Add(normalUrl & Me.Name, True)
            oAddin.Installed = True

            oXL.Quit
            Set oXL = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```